# Minimum Space Between UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Ive been trying to increase the distance between cells using the `UICollectionView` I cant seem to change the spacing between the cells. My goal is to try and have a single cell centred and on horizontal swipe to go to the next cell. I've tried using this:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)
collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{

return 100.0f;
}
```

but this doesn't seem to increase the spacing between the cells. I understand that the cells can be any width or height but I need to keep the dimensions as they are in order to fit all the content into the cells. Im using objective c and creating the cells programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out guys!!! VoyageCN gave me a hint. All that needed to be done was use `minimumLineSpacing` rather than `minimumInteritemSpacing` and that solved it. Now I need to figure out a way to have them all spaced out evenly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you complete the method `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to set size of your cell?

And you need to know when you set minimumInteritemSpacing that is not main actual interitem spacing

Comment: Yes, I have set the width and height depending on the orientation. I also have this in the `- (void)loadView` function: `layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0f;`